# Symfony2 Tree Builder unlimited nesting level

Tags: symfony, yaml

Is is possible to have an yml tree builder in symfony2 that matches this format :

```
X:
   name: ---
   #other fields... 
   X:
       name: -------
       #other fields 
       X:
           name: -----
           #other fields 
           X:
               # and so on .....
```

in other words , an unlimited nesting ?

Answer (score 0):

In theory there is nothing against this, although in practise there are some natural limits to the nesting:

- limits imposed by the maximum file size (determined by your filesystem and/or disc capacity).
- the YAML parser, processes the file recursively might run out of stack space to store context. This is limited by your available memory and/or restrictions by the PHP interpreter.

In fact the only way to represent deeply nested mappings is in either this block mode or in flow mode and the latter will give even longer lines.

Whether the result is humanly readable and useful is of course a different matter.